# Переменные из другого класса имеющего параметры

Tags: java

Из класса имеющего в конструкторе аргументы не могу получить переменные для использования их в другом классе. Через getx() не получается.

И через

```
Class cl; 

System.out.println(cl.x);
```

также не могу получить "x" класса Class.

**Вопрос: как можно получить "х" и все остальные переменные?**

Comment: Из вопроса ничего понятно. Вы хотите получить список полей класса? Или значения полей экземпляра класса? Приведите полный фрагмент кода.

Comment: Я хочу получить в одном классе переменную из другого. Например мне нужен "х" : System.out.println(anotherclass.x), но не даёт мне другой класс свой "х". В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Также я пробовал System.out.println(getx()); ошибка - Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить переменную из другого класса тебе нужно сделать getter
Вот простой пример, в котором в класс Main передается переменная x из класса AnotherClass

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(); //создаем экземпляр класса
        System.out.println(anotherClass.getx()); // обращаемся к методу класса через его экземпляр
    }
}


public class AnotherClass {
    int x = 5;

    public int getx(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

Подробнее почитай про инкапсуляцию, сеттеры и геттеры

В случае когда есть параметры, то значит у этого класса есть конструктор.
Вот простой пример

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 5; //создаем переменную и инциализируем ее, так просто так создать переменную в методе нельзя
        AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(number); //создаем экземпляр класса и передаем в него нашу переменную
        System.out.println(anotherClass.getx()); // обращаемся к методу класса через его экземпляр
    }
}


public class AnotherClass {
    int x;

    AnotherClass( int a){//конструктор, в который мы передаем нашу 5 в виде "а"
        x = a;// передаем в x значение a
    }

    public int getx(){
        return x;//возвращаем значение x
}
}
```

UPD. Ответ на комментарий.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherAnotherClass myObj = new AnotherAnotherClass(); //создаем экземпляр нового класса
        AnotherClass myObj2 =  myObj.getMyClass();//получаем экземпляр класса AnotherClass, который мы создавали в AnotherAnotherClass
        System.out.print( myObj2.getx() );

    }
}


public class AnotherClass {
    int x;

    AnotherClass( int a){//конструктор, в который мы передаем нашу 5 в виде "а"
        x = a;// передаем в x значение a
    }

    public int getx(){
        return x;//вовзращаем значение x
}
}

public class AnotherAnotherClass {
    int x = 5;
    AnotherClass simpleObject = new AnotherClass(x);

    public AnotherClass getMyClass(){
        return simpleObject; //возвращаем созданный экземпляр класса AnotherClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за внимание. А что если у AnotherClass есть параметры? Тогда в классе Main при создании экземпляра он просит указать их. Но у меня уже AnotherClass с параметрами вызван в другом классе.

Comment: Это я понимаю, я уже создал экземпляр этого класса в другом классе и параметры нужные ввел. AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(number); теперь мне надо в еще одном классе получить переменные AnotherClass, но не надо вписать аргументы, иначе я их обновлю и программа не будет работать. Дак вот как не обновляя  параметры создать экземпляр класса и получать от него переменные?

Comment: В таком случае экземпляр класса не надо создавать, а просто получить экземпляр класса AnotherClass из того класса, в котором ты его создал. Пример, я написал выше.

Comment: Ах тыж мой ювелир.